Timeout Error in Hardhat Staging Test with Chainlink VRF and automation on sepolia network
I am encountering a timeout error while running a staging test for my Lottery smart contract using Hardhat. The test is supposed to integrate with live Chainlink VRF and Chainlink Keepers, but it keeps timing out. Here's the test code:
const { network, getNamedAccounts, ethers, deployments } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains } = require("../../helper-hardhat-config")
const { expect, assert } = require("chai")

developmentChains.includes(network.name)
    ? describe.skip
    : describe("Raffle staging test", () => {
          let lottery, lotteryEnteranceFee, deployer

          beforeEach(async () => {
              deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer
              const lotteryDeployed = await deployments.get("Lottery")
              lottery = await ethers.getContractAt("Lottery", lotteryDeployed.address)
              lotteryEnteranceFee = await lottery.getEnteranceFee()
          })

          describe("fulfillRandomWords", () => {
              it("works with live Chainlink Keepers and Chainlink VRF, we get a random winner", async () => {
                  // enter the lottery
                  console.log("Setting up test...")
                  const startingTimeStamp = await lottery.getLatestTimeStamp()
                  const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
                  const winnerStartingBalance = await accounts[0].getBalance()

     

             console.log("Setting up listener...")
                      await new Promise

(async (resolve, reject) => {
                      console.log("here 1")

                  //setup listener before we eneter the lottery
                  //Just in case the blockchain moves really fast
                  lottery.once("WinnerPicked", async () => {
                      console.log("WinnerPicked event fired!")
                      try {
                          //add our asserts here
                          const recentWinner = await lottery.getRecentWinner()
                          const lotteryState = await lottery.getLotteryState()
                          const winnerEndingBalance = await accounts[0].getBalance()
                          const endingTimeStamp = await lottery.getLatestTimeStamp()

                          //   Assert that the player list is reset
                          await expect(lottery.getPalyers(0)).to.be.reverted
                          assert.equal(recentWinner.toString(), accounts[0].address)
                          assert.equal(lotteryState, 0)
                          assert.equal(
                              winnerEndingBalance.toString(),
                              winnerStartingBalance.add(lotteryEnteranceFee).toString(),
                          )
                          assert(endingTimeStamp > startingTimeStamp)
                          resolve()
                      } catch (error) {
                          console.log("Assertion error :", error)
                          reject(error)
                      }
                  })

                  //Then entering the lottery
                  try {
                      console.log("Entering Lottery...")
                      const tx = await lottery.enterLottery({ value: lotteryEnteranceFee })
                      console.log("here 3")
                      await tx.wait(1)
                      console.log("here 4")
                  } catch (error) {
                      console.log("Transcation error :", error)
                      reject(error)
                  }

                  // and this code wont complete until our listener has finished listening!
              })
          })
      })
  })

The command I use to run my staging test:
npx hardhat test --network sepolia

Error Message:
I receive the following error message when running the test:
Error: Timeout of 400000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
at processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)

What I've Tried:

Increasing the Mocha timeout limit in hardhat.config.js.
Ensuring that the Chainlink VRF and Keepers are properly configured and funded on the Sepolia testnet.
Confirming that the contract is deployed correctly and that the enterLottery function is called with the correct entrance fee.

Additional Information:
The test works as expected locally with a mock Chainlink VRF and Keepers.
The event WinnerPicked doesn't seem to be emitted, leading to the timeout.
I've checked my funding for Chainlink subscriptions, and everything seems in order.
Github Repository:
https://github.com/Alisha-Reddy/lottery_smartContract
What could be causing this timeout issue when trying to test with live Chainlink VRF and Keepers on Sepolia testnet?

Please add the commands that you're using to run the staging test.

Just added the command. Please check it once

In your Lottery.sol file:

Make the checkUpeep() function as view:
function checkUpkeep(bytes memory /*checkData*/ )
     public
     view
     override
     returns (bool upKeepNeeded, bytes memory /* performData*/ )
 {
      // Function body
 }



In your helper-hardhat-config.js file:
In the networkConfig object, corresponding to 11155111 (i.e., Eth-Sepolia network):

Change the the value of vrfCoordinatorV2 from 0x9ddfaca8183c41ad55329bdeed9f6a8d53168b1b to 0x9DdfaCa8183c41ad55329BdeeD9F6A8d53168B1B (i.e, the checksummed version of the address).

Change the value of callbackGasLimit from 5000000 to 500000. Basically remove one zero from it.
vrfCoordinatorV2: "0x9DdfaCa8183c41ad55329BdeeD9F6A8d53168B1B"
callbackGasLimit: "500000"



And, deploy the Lottery contract again, add it as a consumer to VRFCoordinatorV2_5, and register a Custom Logic Upkeep corresponding to the deployed Lottery contract.
Also, you need to remove this assert statement:
assert.equal(
    winnerEndingBalance.toString(),
    winnerStartingBalance.add(lotteryEnteranceFee).toString(),
)

Because, it's not considering the gas fees, that need to be subtracted from the winnerEndingBalance, thereby failing the asserted equality.
Now, the staging test should pass:

P.S., You need to remove the resolve() from the last try block, that I've mentioned in the previous version of this answer.

But it's not printing WinnerPicked event fired!

I think the event is not getting triggered.

I’ve checked the logs too. Can you try by doing multiple entries into the lottery, the way you’ve done in case of the unit test?

I did try multple entries but didn't find any change

I’ll debug that on my end, and let you know.

Ok. Thank you in advance

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
